# Combine two class into 1 as anonymous class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

It see like EF not allow to do so, how to actually make it work as I don't want to copy variable from 2 class into 1, I try to access the variable inside each class by this way, is it possible to create something like that?

Anonymous Class

```
public class PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO
{
    public PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO()
    {
    }

    public virtual PurchaseOrderHeader PurchaseOrderHeader { get; set; }

    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework

```
var result = PurchaseOrderHeaders
                 .Join(qbmWBSContext.Suppliers,
                    c => c.SupplierCode,
                    d => d.SupplierCode,
                    (d, c) => new { d, c })
                 .Where(dc => dc.c.CompanyCode == sCompany &&
                     dc.c.RegionalCode == sRegional &&
                     dc.c.SiteCode == sSiteCode &&
                     dc.c.Status == "1")
                 .Select(dc => new PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO
                     {
                         PurchaseOrderHeader = new PurchaseOrderHeader
                         {
                             RecordID = dc.d.RecordID,
                             OrderNumber = dc.d.OrderNumber,
                             SupplierCode = dc.c.SupplierCode
                         },
                         Supplier = new Supplier
                         {
                             SupplierName = dc.c.SupplierName
                         }
                     });
```

**Update**

I manage to found a way

PurchaseOrderDTO

```
public class PurchaseOrderDTO
    {
        public PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO PurchaseOrderHeader { get; set; }
        public PurchaseOrderLineDTO PurchaseOrderLine { get; set; }
        public SupplierDTO Supplier { get; set; }


    }

    public class PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO:PurchaseOrderHeader
    {
    }

    public class PurchaseOrderLineDTO:PurchaseOrderLine
    {
        //public decimal BalanceQuantity { get; set; }

    }

    public class SupplierDTO : Supplier
    {

    }
```

Comment: You need to load all data from database to memory first, then create any classes you want. EF itself can return only table fields' content, it's not aware of any classes.

Comment: Anyway I'd recommend you to write the same query in Query Syntax (i.e. `from c in PurchaseOrderHeaders` etc), it would be much more readable.

Comment: This is not an anonoymous class - you have given it a name: PurchaseOrderHeaderDTO! I would call it a composite class. Anyway what is the problem - what you have seems fine- what is the exception?

Comment: Why do you join? Isn't there a navigation property like `PurchaseOrderHeader.Supplier`?

Comment: I have error as the linq say that I cannot use it as it is a complex type, there no navigation property, cos the table itself doesnt link to anyone, due to some issue that forsee by the business user, thats y I force to work on another way round